# transforming an idl to java

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to convert a proprietary, third party IDL into java.  I downloaded the IDL, opened up cmd.exe, navigated to the directory containing the IDL files, and then typed in the following command which was given explicitly by the provider of the third party IDL:

```
java com.sun.tools.corba.se.idl.toJavaPortable.Compile -fallTIE -pkgPrefix types org.hl7 -pkgPrefix CTSMAPI org.hl7 -pkgPrefix CTSVAPI org.hl7 CTSVAPI.idl
```

Unfortunately, this is throwing the following error in the command line:

```
Error: could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.corba.se.idl.toJavaPortable.Compile
```

I googled and found the definition of the class [at this link](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/tools/corba/se/idl/toJavaPortable/Compile.html).

I typed in `java` in the command prompt and got a list of methods, indicating that I can call java from the command prompt in that directory.  Other web sites indicate that `com.sun.tools.corba.se.idl.toJavaPortable.Compile` has been a part of the jdk since at least version 1.3.  **So why am I getting this error?**

Answer (score 1):

The provider doesn't know what he's talking about. You should use the 'idlj' tool, with the same or corresponding arguments, not this undocumented invocation.

You may be getting the error because you're running the JRE 'java', not the JDK one. But it's wrong wrong wrong. Use [`idlj`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/idlj.html).

Comment: ***This is not my suggestion at all.*** There is a JDK ***tool*** called 'idlj'. Use it. I didn't say anything about adding a 'j'.

Comment: ***The 'idlj' tool*** will call the 'idlj' tool. You shouldn't be using 'java'. You shouldn't be using the undocumented class name. You shouldn't be being told to do these things.

Comment: Don't patronize me thanks. I'm not the one at fault here. All I did was provide a correct answer that solved your problem.